# Scrapy Web Spider Xpath Selector

Tags: for-loop, xpath, scrapy, response, selector

How could i get this to work by using this:

Spider

```
for sel in response:
       item = DmozItem()
       item['title'] = sel.xpath("//td[@class='nblu  tabcontent']/a/big/text()").extract()
       item['link'] = sel.xpath("//td[@class='nblu tabcontent']/a/@href").extract()
       yield item
```

instead of using this:

```
  for sel in response.xpath("//td[@class='nblu tabcontent']"):
       item = DmozItem()
       item['title'] = sel.xpath("a/big/text()").extract()
       item['link'] = sel.xpath("a/@href").extract()
       yield item
```

the first one clearly does not work, looking for a alternative that does that same thing as the 2nd code in the form of the first code.

Thanks, Charlie

Comment: What is wrong with the second snippet? Sorry, but I cannot understand the question. Thanks.

Comment: Agree with @alecxe that your question is confusing, but note that in the first case `@class='nblu   tabcontent'` with multiple spaces is not equivalent to `@class='nblu tabcontent'` with one space.

Comment: Apologies,extra space is typo. Remeber @alecxe, mysql not enough parametres question u answered, faced the same issue again if i dint use the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can code directly as following

```
item = DmozItem()
item['title'] = response.xpath("//td[@class='nblu   tabcontent']/a/big/text()").extract()
item['link'] = response.xpath("//td[@class='nblu tabcontent']/a/@href").extract()
yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath function [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains).

```
//td[contains(@class, 'nblu') and contains(@class, 'tabcontent')]
```